# Google Maps Uncaught TypeError: b.has is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

We are including the Google Maps API V3 in our internal systems with the below code:

script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&libraries=places,geometry"

This was working until a few hours ago (9am AEST) now in the console all that's returned is:

**Uncaught TypeError: b.has is not a function** from https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/35/3/map.js

Is anyone else facing the same problem?

How can I fix it when the code is included from Google's servers?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (preferably a StackOverflow code snippet).

Comment: Maybe try a different (older/more stable) [version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had the same problem, using an older version fixed it for now:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=quarterly&key=API_KEY
```

Long time fix - You probably overwrote the native window.Map, see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: THANK YOU. I'm so glad someone else had the same problem

Comment: @JRT2018 Me too!  You probably also have an own window.map property like me, which is a reserved word.. Renaming it should fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me from a lot of troubleshooting. I had a wrapper around the Google Maps API called Map, renaming that solved the issue for me.

For posterity and SEO, my error message was "j.keys is not a function".

Answer (score 4):

We have the same problem here. We had a link to the last version :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...

If we force the version to 3.34 it does the trick :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.34&key=

Version 3.35 is not working. Google has replaced a function used with maps (hashmaps, not graphic maps) which is used to search for a key.
hasOwnProperty(b, c) --> b.has(c)

Problem is that "b" does not have the function "has".

I do not have much more information at this point. We are continuing the investigation.

Good luck everyone.

Regards
Vincent

Edit :
OK, now I do understand what happened. Somewhere in our map, we are re-defining the prototype "Map". This protoype does not contain the method "has" and maybe "set" too (that was the case for us).
You have to search for something like "Map.prototype." in jour JS files. This will give you the hint for where you have to correct your JS.
If you can't suppress this prototype, you will have to redefine the missing methods.
For example, we had the following prototype :

```
function Map(){
    this.obj = {};
    this.count = 0;
}
```

We had to complete this prototype with the following methods :

```
Map.prototype.has=function(key){
    return this.obj[key] !== undefined;
}

Map.prototype.set = function(key, value){
    var oldValue = this.obj[key];
    if(oldValue == undefined){
        this.count++;
    }
    this.obj[key] = value;
    return oldValue;
}
```

With this correction, version 3.35 of GoogleMaps JS is working.

I hope it helps.

Regards,
Vincent

Comment: Map is now a global EcmaScript object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map. You are better off using this name in your function.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem but with a different error that suddenly appeared:

**map.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: this.j.keys is not a function**

No problems when forcing the version to be 3.34 but 3.35 wouldn't load the map or markers.

After of course hours of trying to figure out the issue, renaming a js class so it was no longer called Map fixed it.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question, if you face an issue consider asking a new question yourself.

Comment: @xashru it was the same problem with a different error message which I got no hits for when trying to resolve the problem and figured it might help someone else with the same error - should it have been a comment instead? A new question that I answer myself/link to this one?

Comment: yes you could have just added as a comment to the accepted answer.

Comment: ah I don't have enough reputation to add a comment there

Comment: can you please give some more details about how you fixed this issue. Like which javascript file you renamed?

Comment: @ANCHALOSEY it's a js file map.js used only in an app I've been building, and the class was called Map which caused a conflict. I changed:
`class Map extends Controller`
to
`class Mapper extends Controller`
and it resolved the issue.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. I am glad to have read your solution. It is strange that Google Maps suddenly exposed the 'Map' class.

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing. Static mature code in high-traffic app. Working for 8+ years. Until this morning. Turned out we had been using a reserved ID claimed by the GMap API for one of our internal object instances ("Map"). Have no idea why it decided today was the day to blow. We were linking in older version (3.29) of the API. Something clearly changed on the Google end of things.